# Cannot use ownCloud sync client on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: sync, linux-mint, owncloud, qt

I'm trying to use the official ownCloud client on Linux Mint 17.3.  The version I'm using, version 2.2.1, has stopped working.  When I try to launch it from the command line, it gives the following error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN9QKeychain15ReadPasswordJob6setKeyERK7QString
```

So I tried reinstalling the program.  However, it gives an error about the following unmet dependency:

```
libqt5core5a (>= 5.4.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is to be installed
```

I don't know how to move forward with this.  Also of mention, here's the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud-client.list` file:

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.04/ /
```

I don't know how to fix this problem.  Building from sources does not work since I don't have the very latest version of KDE Frameworks.  If there is an alternative to syncing my files with my ownCloud instance I would like to hear it.

Comment: Yes, there is: use Windows! Linux is not ready for the desktop. In your case, the qt5-lib might be in some ubuntu-backported repository. But Mint 18 is coming out soon (next month?) so you could maybe also just wait. This is the huge disadvantage of the typical fixed-release distribution-system. And rolling-release distros are very unstable.

Comment: _"Yes, there is: use Windows! Linux is not ready for the desktop."_
Wow, and I'm suppose to care how?  Anyway, thank you for your "response".

Comment: Read the second part of my response again. I think it is supported in the ubuntu-backports repository (Trusty I believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downgrading `libqt5keychan0` to version 6.2-1.1 from the OpenSuSe repos provided by ownCloud I finally got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 17.3 is based on Ubuntu 14.04, not 15.04, as you assume in the repository list. Instead, use the following repository for the owncloud binaries:

> deb
>   http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.04/
>   /

Like this it should be able to resolve all dependencies.

Comment: Ah good, something that's usable.  See what happens when you don't act like a jerk?

Comment: Drat, that didn't work either; I still get the error.  Well, thanks for the effort, anyway.

Comment: That's weird. On my Linux Mint 17.3 it works just fine like that. But I don't remember if I am using Cinnamon or MATE. Do you use additional custom repositories?

Comment: I am using MATE 64bit. Just looked it up.

Comment: I'm using Cinnamon.  And I don't think I'm using any custom repositories.